# Bot framework emulator not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, emulation, botframework

I started learning bot framework last week, and i decided to start off with the default bot project that returns your input and its number of character. But unfortunately, I couldn't test the bot application in bot emulator. It can't just send my input. It displays "couldn't send" whenever I forward an input. 
My endpoint url which is http://localhost:3979/api/messages/ is correctly written there. 
What could be wrong? I'm just a starter in bot framework and bot building.

Comment: What version of the bot emulator are you using?  as of 2017.3.5, the latest version is v3.5.25 and can be downloaded from here: https://emulator.botframework.com

Comment: That's the version I'm using -- 3.5.25

Comment: The emulator display errors in the right bottom window. What is the error? Start your project under debugger, enable handle all exception. Do you have any?

Comment: Yes! [09:49:11]  Checking for new version...
[09:49:20] 
Command failed: 4294967295 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'emulator.botframework.com' at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSucc

Comment: Did you configure tunneling? https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-emulator/wiki/Tunneling-(ngrok)

Comment: My bot is hosted locally. So is there need configuring tunneling?

Comment: No. Are you leaving blank the App Id and the App secret in the emulator?

Answer (score 6):

As I'm not aware of the exact code which you are trying to execute, I'd suggest few points to be checked again.

Checkpoints:

1. Make sure you are running the code in debug mode with any browser (Edge, chrome, explorer etc.) and then run in the emulator.
2. Configure or link the emulator with ngrok. (Though it is not required when running locally but it may resolve if the emulator is not working with firewall issues)
3. Please check the Microsoft App Id and Microsoft App Password are the same in emulator and Web.config file.
4. Try with blank Microsoft App Id and Microsoft App Password in both Web.config file and emulator.
5. Check if the endpoints on the browser and emulator are the same
6. If you are encountering other errors like 401, 405, 500 please check this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/08/01/bot-framework-405-method-not-allowed-401-unauthorized-and-500-internal-server-error-getting-started).
7. In case if all the check points are right and you are still encountering an issue while running the code in emulator, there might be an issue with the code or reference libraries. You can also check the working [example](https://github.com/fanidamj/BotSamplePublished).

Answer (score 0):

Check your visual studio .bot file. It should be like this.......

```
    {
        "name": "EmulatorBot",
        "description": "",
        "services": [
            {
                "type": "endpoint",[enter image description here][1]
                "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
                "name": "EmulatorBot20181123022900",
                "id": "25"
            }
        ],
        "padlock": "",
        "version": "2.0",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\suraj.tiwari\\Desktop\\Bot NK\\EmulatorBot\\EmulatorBot.bot",
        "overrides": null
    }
```

Add an Endpoint for your bot

```
    Endpoint url : http://localhost:3978/api/messages
    Name : EmulatorBot20181123022900
```

Comment: Bot files are deprecated.