# Getting Error 500 in Microsoft Bot in Remotely Hosted URL

Tags: botframework, ngrok

I was building a bot. I successfully tested in Localhost then i published the solution on a URL.
In emulator i am able to connect to it but when trying to communicate in chat it is giving error 500. while same code on localhost is running successfully. I tried to Configured through NGROK but still getting same error.

LocalHost was like ->  http://localhost:3979/api/meesages
RemoteHost was like -> https://botapplication120170207010554.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

I am able to connect through emulator but unable to communicate.

Comment: Are u configuring the right Microsoft App ID and Microsoft App Password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot framework emulator not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611413/bot-framework-emulator-not-working)

Comment: Yes i am using the right one,. I am able to connect but unable to query.