# How to resolve "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Authorization for Microsoft App ID xxx failed with status code Unauthorized"

Tags: .net, f#, botframework

I've created a simple bot using the .net framework. Messages are received but when replying, the application throw the exception below

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Authorization for Microsoft App ID xxx failed with status code Unauthorized and reason phrase 'Unauthorized' ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.JwtTokenRefresher.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.JwtTokenRefresher.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotState.<GetConversationDataWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotStateExtensions.<GetConversationDataAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ConnectorStore.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotDataStore<Microsoft-Bot-Connector-BotData>-LoadAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore.<LoadFromInnerAndCache>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotDataStore<Microsoft-Bot-Connector-BotData>-LoadAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1.<LoadData>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1.<LoadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTaskManagerBotDataLoader.<LoadAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<SendAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Authorization for Microsoft App ID 9d88e9f7-289e-45d2-8215-8f539955335d failed with status code Unauthorized and reason phrase 'Unauthorized' ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.JwtTokenRefresher.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.JwtTokenRefresher.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotState.<GetConversationDataWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotStateExtensions.<GetConversationDataAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ConnectorStore.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotDataStore<Microsoft-Bot-Connector-BotData>-LoadAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore.<LoadFromInnerAndCache>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotDataStore<Microsoft-Bot-Connector-BotData>-LoadAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1.<LoadData>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1.<LoadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTaskManagerBotDataLoader.<LoadAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<SendAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()<---
```

Code

```
open System
open System.Text
open Hopac
open Hopac.Hopac
open Microsoft.Bot.Connector
open Suave
open Suave.Successful
open Suave.Filters
open Suave.Operators
open Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs
open Newtonsoft.Json
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals


type RootDialog () =
  let rec onMessageReceived (context: IDialogContext) (result: IAwaitable<obj>) =
    job {

      //let! activity = result
      do! context.PostAsync ("Sweet") |> Job.awaitUnitTask
      context.Wait (ResumeAfter onMessageReceived) }
    |> startAsTask |> unbox
  interface IDialog<obj> with
    member x.StartAsync (context: IDialogContext) =
      context.Wait (ResumeAfter (onMessageReceived))
      Task.CompletedTask


let getActivity request =
  let body = request.rawForm |> Encoding.UTF8.GetString
  let activity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity> (body)
  activity


let handleSystemMessage (activity: Activity) =
  match activity.Type with 
  | ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData
  | _ -> ()


let post (activity: Activity) ctx =
  job {
    match activity.Type with
    | ActivityTypes.Message -> 
        do! Conversation.SendAsync (activity, fun () -> RootDialog() :> _) |> Job.awaitUnitTask
    | _ -> handleSystemMessage activity
    return! OK "Got it" ctx }


let part =
  choose [
    POST >=> path "/bot/messages" >=> request (getActivity >> (fun a b -> post a b |> Job.toAsync)) ]
```

PS:

I followed the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/troubleshoot-authentication-problems) and it fails at step 3. Everything works fine when security is disabled.

Checking with fiddler shows that multiple requests are made to `login.microsoftonline.com` and all such requests are successful so I don't think it is the credentials. What could be the problem?

Comment: We need to see your code if we're going to have any hope of helping you.

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: I'm reading [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991355/authorization-for-microsoft-app-id-xxx-failed-with-status-code-forbidden-and-rea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991355/authorization-for-microsoft-app-id-xxx-failed-with-status-code-forbidden-and-rea) and the `OAuthScope` value is `api.botframework.com/.default`.  If this applies to me, is there a way to change it to the `graph.microsoft.com/.default`?

Comment: Not sure if it was the right thing to do but got it to working by adding the line `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl (activity.ServiceUrl)` before `do! Conversation.SendAsync ...`

Comment: Yes, adding a call to TrustServiceUrl is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Richard you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the solution was to add the line below before `do! Conversation.SendAsync ...`

`MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl (activity.ServiceUrl)`

PS:
I'm not really sure why this must be done but any comments on the reason for this might help make the solution more meaningful.